# A stick of length 1 is split at a random position $B\sim U(0, 1)$. Let $X$ be the length of the longer stick. What is the PDF of $X$?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional

A stick of length 1 is split at a random position $B$ where $B$ ~ $U(0, 1)$. Let $X$ be the length of the longer stick. What is the CDF of $X$?

This problem is challenging me. I know that the cdf of X is $F_x(x) = 2x-1$ when $0.5 \le x < 1$, and $0 \text{ when } x < 0.5 \text{ and } 1 \text{ when } x \ge 1$. My trouble starts when arriving at this answer.

The way I am attempting to solve the problem is as follows:

Let's first assume $0.5 \le x < 1$. Then, $F_x(x) = P(X\le x)$. Here, I know that the problem needs to be split into two cases, namely, when $B > 0.5$ and $B \le 0.5$, and the value of $X$ is either $B$ or $1 - B$ depending on the size of $B$. I figured that I would attempt to split the problem into the two cases as follows:

$$P(X\le x) = P(B \le x |B>0.5) + P(1 - B \le x|B\le0.5). $$

The issue is that it gives the wrong answer when you attempt to use a conditional probability, and rather, we should be splitting the problem up like this:

$$P(X\le x) = P(B \le x \cap B>0.5) + P(1 - B \le x \cap B\le0.5). $$

I just don't quite understand why using a conditional probability here is wrong. $X$ is only equal to $B$ when $B>0.5$, so I figured the first probability should be $P(X\le x | B > 0.5)$ because $X=B$ given that $B < 0.5$

Could someone give an intuitive explanation as to why it is incorrect to use conditional probability like I tried to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, there is really no need to invoke any "conditional probability" argument.  The CDF of $X$ can be directly evaluated as follows:

By the setting, $X$ can be expressed as $X = \max(B, 1 - B)$, and $X \geq 1/2$.  For $x \in [1/2, 1)$, we have
\begin{align}
F_X(x) &= P(\max(B, 1 - B) \leq x) = P(B \leq x, 1 - B \leq x) = 
P(1 - x \leq B \leq x) \\
&= 2x - 1.
\end{align}
Obviously, when $x < 1/2$, $F_X(x) = 0$; and when $x \geq 1$, $F_X(x) = 1$.

Now, back to your question "*why it is incorrect to use conditional probability like I tried to do*". You seem to try to use the law of total probability, but failed to apply it correctly (in that you dropped out probabilities of conditioning events). Your "formula":
$$P(X\le x) = P(B \le x |B>0.5) + P(1 - B \le x|B\le 0.5)$$
should be corrected as
\begin{align}
& P[X \leq x] = P[X \leq x|B > 0.5]\color{red}{P[B > 0.5]} + 
P[X \leq x|B \leq 0.5]\color{red}{P[B \leq 0.5]} \\
=& 0.5P[B \leq x|B > 0.5] + 0.5P[1 - B \leq x|B \leq 0.5] \\
=& 0.5 \times \frac{P[0.5 < B \leq x]}{P(B > 0.5)} + 
0.5 \times \frac{P[1 - x \leq B \leq 0.5]}{P(B \leq 0.5)} \\
=& x - 0.5 + (0.5 - 1 + x) = 2x - 1, 
\end{align}
which meets the expectation.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to compute the *pdf* of $X$ which has value $B$ when $B > \frac  12$ and value $1-B$ when $B < \frac 12$.  Since both $B$ and $1-B$ are $U(0,1)$ random variables, the pdf of $X$ is easily determined to be $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}2,& \frac 12 < x < 1,\\0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ from which one gets that the CDF is
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}2x-1,& \frac 12 < x < 1,\\0, &x \leq 0,\\ 1, & x\geq 1. 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

It might easier to reason by doing a change of variable of $u = B-0.5$. Then $X = |u|+0.5$. And clearly $p(u = u_0) = p(u = -u_0)$. So you can just take the PDF for $u >0$, which is just the uniform distribution.

It's not clear what you mean by "x", let alone what $F_x(x)$ means. How can you have the same variable be both a parameter and an argument?